# Please suggest how to check AB testing in magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2

If any Extension available please suggest me i need to test imagege and video level for the customer experience.

Answer (score 0):

you can buy below extension and testing.

[Magento 2 A/B Testing Extension](https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-ab-testing-extension/)

Comment: but it is not satisfied for image and video variant only for font size,font color,text change.I need one cms page example test.html page have Banner using AB testing change it as video then i have to compare take the report which one is have visted one